# Expose sub components to Delphi designer

Tags: delphi, composite-component

I have created a component inheriting `TFrame` and added an ActionList and ToolBar to the frame as I want to make a base form available to other projects and developers. The question is: how can I expose the ActionList property at design time? The ActionList is showing in the object inspector and I can see it's events and properties, but the actions inside the ActionList are not available at design time.

More details:

I have created a class inheriting from `TFrame` and added an `TActionList` in the Delphi IDE designer. Then I added it to a package and installed it as a component. Now I can drop that component on a form and it adds the whole frame I designed to the form. I see the ActioList in the object inspector, but the problem is I cannot see the actions inside the ActionList. I need to add actions to ActionList on the forms which are using the component.

[image]

Comment: The lack of answers seems to be related to the lack of information. Please rephrase/extend your question.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Delphi 2009 (if I get it right).

Comment: added more detail. I cannot add a screenshot because I don't have enough reputation!

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Delphi 2007, either. When I drop the TFrame from the Component Palette, I can see the `ActionList` on the frame, and can click on the `ToolBar` and see it's properties just fine. You're missing some details here that would allow people to help you. (Tested on D2007 since @TLama tested on 2009 to make sure it wasn't an earlier version of the VCL issue.)

Comment: Actually, I see the perceived issue. It's not showing in the Object Inspector (the ActionList does, but there's no `Actions` property), but you can right-click the ActionList on the frame and choose `Action List Editor`, and the actions are in fact there where you'd expect. This isn't an issue, though; dropping a new ActionList on a form doesn't show the Actions in the OI, either. You have to right-click and choose `Action List Editor` that way, too.

Comment: I don't see "Action List Editor" when right-click. I use Delphi 2007. I have uploaded image. thanks TLama